# create_stack error No such file or directory

Tags: python, openstacksdk

I'm trying to create stack using working connection (i've already created an image) using openstacksdk but there issome problem with `environment_files` namelly:

```
File "my_openstack.py", line 44, in <module>
    conn.create_stack(name='test', template_file='test_heat.yaml', environment_files='test_heat.env')
  File "/home/ds/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/cloud/openstackcloud.py", line 1227, in create_stack
    env_paths=environment_files)
  File "/home/ds/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/cloud/_heat/template_utils.py", line 209, in process_multiple_environments_and_files
    include_env_in_files=include_env_in_files)
  File "/home/ds/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/cloud/_heat/template_utils.py", line 263, in process_environment_and_files
    raw_env = request.urlopen(env_url).read()
  File "/opt/ds/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/ds/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/ds/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/ds/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/ds/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1336, in file_open
    return self.open_local_file(req)
  File "/opt/ds/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1376, in open_local_file
    raise URLError(msg)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ds/t'>
```

every file:
`test_heat.yaml`,
`test_heat.env` and
`my_openstack.py`
are in `/home/ds`

My code:

```py
conn.create_stack(name='test', template_file='test_heat.yaml', environment_files='test_heat.env')
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as possible

`conn.create_stack(name='test', template_file='test_heat.yaml', environment_files=['test_heat.env]')`

`template_utils.py` requires the list